# Populating a ListView with an ArrayList Adapter isn't working - items are there but not being displayed

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

**Edit 3** I'm submitting a new question, as I've realized that the original question here is not actually the problem.

So, I've got a Fragment that gets the files from my app's Internal Storage, then lists them out in a ListView. I'm doing this with an ArrayList for the file names, and an Adapter to population the ListView with those items. If I debug, I see that all the items are in the Array List just like they should be, but for whatever reason they aren't being shown in the list view. I have absolutely no idea what is going on as I've made a new test app using the exact same code and it works perfectly.

ListerFrag.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_templates, container, false);

    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.templateFilesList);

    ArrayList<String> templateList = new ArrayList<String>();

    File myDir = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
    File[] templateFiles = myDir.listFiles();

    if(templateFiles != null){
        for(File file : templateFiles){
            templateList.add(file.getName());
        }
    }


    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            templateList);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    return view;
}
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="-"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/my_templates"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
/>

// relevant ListView
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/templateFilesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

</ListView>
```

I have am very confused.

**Edit:** I'd like to emphasize that the file "instant-run" is being displayed. By default that file is inside the default Internal Storage directory. It is the first item in my ArrayList. I find it odd that the first file is being recognized and displayed, but the rest aren't. Even though they're in the ArrayList (verified via logcat).

**Edit 2:** Some more weirdness. If I explicitly tell the code to display, say, listItem[1] it works perfectly. So I'm zeroing in on an issue with the for loop maybe.

Comment: Did you forgot to call notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: Did not call that. Would I call it on my adapter? Edit: Just tried that "arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged" after my for-loop, nothing's changed.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little doubtful about your last 2 lines. Try:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: "(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, templateList);" is underlined in red and says "Cannot resolve constructor."

Comment: Try: `ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);`

Comment: Maybe your `targetList` is empty. Try printing it out.

Comment: Google isn't helping me much here. What is/how do I print out the targetList?

Comment: Use loop as: `for(String str: templateList) System.out.println(str);`

Comment: Comes out just like it should: 

I/System.out: instant-run

I/System.out: tester1
 I/System.out: tester2
 I/System.out: tester3
I/System.out: tester4
I/System.out: tester5
I/System.out: tester6
I/System.out: tester7

Comment: Still only prints/lists item 1, "instant-run." It's so weird.

Comment: Alright, so I've narrowed down the problem. When I list it manually like this: 
        templateList.add(templateFiles[0].getName());
        templateList.add(templateFiles[1].getName());

templateFiles[0] is the only one that gets listed. If I do this:

        templateList.add(templateFiles[1].getName());
        templateList.add(templateFiles[0].getName());

Only [1] gets shown. So it's somehow not interpreting anything after the first.